# What are some effective strategies for defending resource bases with two beaches?

Tags: boom-beach

Resource bases with two beach fronts pose some interesting challenges when it comes to defending them compared to bases that have only one beach. For instance, it is much more difficult to cover both beaches with defensive towers, where that is an effective tactic on bases with a single beach.

What are some effective strategies when it comes to defending resource bases with two beaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given it's been a while I've played this, here's my favourite.
I like placing them between both beaches, so the towers from one beach can help the towers on the other beach. I place short range weapons like flame throwers very close to the beaches, and long range towers like sniper towers and cannons further away to help on both fronts. Of course further away from one another that they aren't too easy of a target for barages etc.

Answer (score 0):

Flamethrowers, are excellent when scooted up real close to the beach. Zookas, Tanks, and Grenadiers can out range flamethrowers. But when they get out of the landing craft, they are already to close. For the same reason, keep rocket launchers away from the beach. The rocket launchers should be barley in range of one another. But **NEVER** leave the outpost or rocket launchers undefended. Because of the dead zone, a rocket launcher should **always** have help in defending itself.

Comment: This is good general defensive guidelines. But with two beaches, there's only so many defenses you can put right next to the beach. What do you do when you have two beaches to defend but a limited amount of defensive buildings?